# Suggestion about the database to be used with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, database

Can anyone suggest me which database to be used with OpenLayers? I have to store the values in a database table and retrieve them (trivial tasks). Which is better MySQL or PostGIS? Can anybody give benefits of these?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [bostongis comparison](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=sqlserver2008_postgis_mysql_compare) is not a really up-to-date document but it can be a good start, at least to see which aspects is a priority to you, and what you should consider as mandatory or optional to make your choices. The comparison is **generic, not related to openlayers**.

For your OL project, I guess you should also consider the DB availability from your hosting unless you have no constraint regarding this point.

From Postgis, you can natively export a query result as *kml* and *json* (and easily read it with OL), which is I think impossible with MySQL (you'll have a third party call to dynamically create it through any language..)

Comment: +1 POSTGIS all the way! Forget SDE on top of any underlying DBMS.

Answer (score 6):

Postgres with **PostGIS** everytime
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostGIS

More Spatial Functions and control on the database in spatial terms

Comment: MYSQL was hacked at the weekend - by SQL injection - http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/03/28/mysql_hack/

Answer (score 6):

If we are talking about Spatial Database, I would leave MySQL out: it is very much incomplete in respect with other OGC Simple Features SQL implementations like PostGIS (my favourite), Oracle Spatial, SQL Server Spatial or even Spatialite. Or ArcSde as a gateway to its supported RDBMS.

Please note, however, that you do not need to have a spatial database for using OpenLayers. You can feed OpenLayers with any Map Server that provides WFS/WMS/WCS etc... OGC web services implementations.
For example if you are using MapServer, you will be able to feed OpenLayer with any vector layer supported by GDAL/OGR:

[Link](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html)

Given your use case ("store the values in a DB table and retrieve them") I guess you need a WFS-T implementations: you may use GeoServer (with PostGis/Oracle Spatial or MySql) or TinyWFS (only GeoServer) for this.

Note that TinyOWS is going to be included soon in the MapServer project (actually MapServer does not provide WFS-T implementation).

Comment: Why would he need WFS-T support? WFS should be enough for read-only.

Comment: he says: "store the values in a DB table and retrieve them"