# Technical comparison of Oracle and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oracle-dbms

I have searched on google and the archives for a technical comparison of Oracle and PostgreSQL (also MySQL), unsuccessfully.

Is there any comparison that covers more than just the basic differences? Maybe you can give me some comparison?

Comment: Database comparisons has already been discussed into that thread : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7818/suggestion-about-the-database-to-be-used-with-openlayers You will probably get interesting stuff there.

Comment: I want something more complex (like underdark), anyway thanks

Comment: underdark's link is provided in the first answer. And you will get more reading others replies!

Comment: Non technical comment: PostGIS is already being used for serious work. For instance, the Institut Géographique National of France decided to use PostGIS after benchmarking it and propietary solutions like Oracle or DB2. More information about it can be found at http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/casestudies/ign/.

Comment: As this question is stated, this is off-topic and should be asked on http://DBA.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: I do not agree. I asked about DB in contex of GIS and spatial information.

Comment: @com: There is nothing about GIS or spatial information in your question. Maybe you should update your question with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Thesis](http://sdsu-dspace.calstate.edu/handle/10211.10/1953) by Shamal Kiran Matty (2012) '*Comparative study of Oracle Spatial and Postgres Spatial*' discusses quite a lot of issues that might be of interest here.

From the summary:

> However, the research done as a part of this thesis suggests that
>   PostGIS is more advantageous over Oracle Spatial for the reasons
>   stated below:
>
> 1. Cost Savings
> 2. Ease of Integration
> 3. Ease of use
> 4. Superior performance
> 5. Feature rich
> 6. Lower disk usage

(via [@FaunaliaGIS](https://twitter.com/#!/FaunaliaGIS/status/197695053244801024))

Answer (score 11):

Check BostonGIS [Compare SQL Server 2008 R2, Oracle 11G R2, PostgreSQL/PostGIS 1.5 Spatial Features](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=sqlserver2008r2_oracle11gr2_postgis15_compare). If that's too basic: Which topics do you need covered?

MySQL is not usable for serious GIS work.

Comment: Wow, a SQL Server enterprise licence starts at $29000 for a single processor! Thanks good for PostgreSQL running queries with my 4 processors at $0 cost.

Comment: postgres every time... always the bottom line.

Comment: @pablo - the enterprise licence is more for deploying large data farms. The standard edition is a more suitable comparison.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I had found the following [Comparison of Oracle, MySQL and PostgreSQL DBMS](http://www-css.fnal.gov/dsg/external/freeware/mysql-vs-pgsql.html) which i think is a good overview.

Comment: Be aware that this comparison is "very" old (2005).

Comment: You're right! I don't pay attention to that. Thanks to point it. Anyway is good :)